# Why does redirecting lines ≥1022 characters take 83× longer than redirecting lines ≥1021 characters?

Tags: grep, pipe, performance

I have a text file of around 10 MB containing around 50k lines.  When I select all lines ≥1021 bytes and redirect the output to a regular file or pipe it to cat, it takes 0.135s.  When I change this to ≥1022 bytes, it takes 15.9 seconds — a factor 83 longer.  The result is identical.

```
$ time grep '^.{1021,}$' my_file > /tmp/grep1021

real    0m0.135s
user    0m0.120s
sys     0m0.013s
$ time grep '^.{1022,}$' my_file > /tmp/grep1022

real    0m11.483s
user    0m11.036s
sys     0m0.441s
$ cmp /tmp/grep102?
$
```

Time consumption grows quite steeply after that; for lines with ≥2100 characters, it takes 52 seconds (the result still happens to be identical):

```
$ time grep '^.{1200,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m15.903s
user    0m15.182s
sys     0m0.737s
$ time grep '^.{1500,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m27.114s
user    0m24.584s
sys     0m2.545s
$ time grep '^.{1800,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m36.468s
user    0m34.889s
sys     0m1.594s
$ time grep '^.{2100,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m52.164s
user    0m47.949s
sys     0m4.221s
```

It's not due to `grep` alone, which is fast enough by itself:

```
$ time grep '^.{1022,}$' my_file > /dev/null

real    0m0.073s
user    0m0.060s
sys     0m0.012s
$ time grep '^.{3000,}$' my_file > /dev/null

real    0m0.495s
user    0m0.411s
sys     0m0.084s
```

Why is this happening?  My guess is something about chunking, but I can't explain why passing *less* data to the pipe makes it take *much* longer to process.  The boundary is suspiciously close to 1024.

The system is running openSUSE 15.3 with Linux kernel 5.3.18-59.19-default.

More information:

- Adding `--line-buffered` to grep makes no difference
- When using `awk 'length >= n`, the process runs very fast.

```
$ time grep '^.{1021,}$' my_file | wc
    263   30511 1899841

real    0m0.162s
user    0m0.147s
sys     0m0.031s
$ time grep '^.{1022,}$' my_file | wc
    263   30511 1899841

real    0m11.514s
user    0m11.044s
sys     0m0.487s

$ ulimit -p
8
$ time grep --line-buffered '^.{1021,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m0.137s
user    0m0.120s
sys     0m0.027s
$ time grep --line-buffered '^.{1022,}$' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m11.528s
user    0m10.989s
sys     0m0.547s
$ time awk 'length >= 1021' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.041s
sys     0m0.008s
$ time awk 'length >= 1022' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m0.044s
user    0m0.045s
sys     0m0.005s
$ time awk 'length >= 3000' my_file | cat > /dev/null

real    0m0.045s
user    0m0.038s
sys     0m0.012s
```

Comment: could you pipe both results through wc instead of dumping them into /dev/null and report the results

Comment: Can you tell me the ulimit -p output? (And check the higher value....) Humm... Without pipe is the same result....

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009
grep (e.g. GNU version 2.5.1) --line-buffered
try the unbuffer please

Comment: I could believe that the Regular Expression evaluation hits a pathological memory problem at ~ 1K look-aheads (it is probably a state machine). You might compare timings against `awk 'length >= 1022'` to eliminate other factors, for comparison.

Comment: @jf1 Sure!  Edited.  In fact, `| wc -l` was what led me to the discovery originally.  I suspected `wc` at first, but found that piping to `cat` or redirecting to a file revealed the same behaviour.

Comment: @K-att- I've added `ulimit -p`.  What do you mean by "check the higher value"?  I've also tried `--line-buffered`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant It _is_ much faster to use awk, but even grep without piping or redirecting the output to a regular file is much faster.  I notice the slowdown in grep only when piping or redirecting to a regular file.  Added more information.

Comment: What happens if you make awk do a Regex along the same lines of what you are feeding to grep?

Comment: Sorry. Try the unbuffer grep ..... . The line-buffered is the default.

Comment: Hmmh, cannot replicate your finding: no difference between 1021 and 1022, also no slowdown even beyond 1030. Not using SuSe though. Could you provide output of `grep -V`?